# Incorrect Buddypress Links

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, buddypress

I recently installed Buddypress on a new Wordpress site. I'm having a problem getting Buddypress links to work. My site's permalinks are set to 'post-name' (`http://mysite.com/index.php/sample-post/`) but when I click 'Register' for example (a Buddypress link) it goes to `http://mysite.com/register`.

Anyone know how I can change Buddypress link structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should NOT be `index.php/` in your permalinks.
Go to Permalinks admin page and remove it using input. And check that you have `.htaccess` file in the root of your WP install.
[This codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) will be useful for you as well.

Comment: So Buddypress can only work with that exact permalink structure, and no others?

Comment: Yes, you are right. At least now BuddyPress doesn't support `index.php` in urls.